# Selenium - returning all text within an xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I have the below code which is supposed to return all the text within a given xpath. This xpath corresponds to the first row of EPG data for the channel NPO 1, however I am receiving nothing back:

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

sys.path.append("G:\\Python36\\mypath")

chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://tvepg.eu/en/netherlands/epg/main")

link_path = '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[215]/td[2]'

link_path2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(link_path)

for link in link_path2:
   
    print link.text
    
driver.quit()
```

...any ideas as to what I need to change?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you are after this or not.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and use the following xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://tvepg.eu/en/netherlands/epg/main")
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@class='grid-container main-table']/tbody//tr[1]/td[1]//img[@class='card-img-topa']")))
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute("alt"))
```

**Output**:

```
NPO 1
NPO 2
NPO 1 extra
NPO 2 extra
RTL 4
RTL 5
SBS6
RTL 7
Net5
RTL 8
SBS9
RTL Lounge
```

Comment: close enough. i had to adapt it substantially to get it to do exactly what i wanted, but mine issue was not defining the xpaths correctly, which you helped me fix, so deserving of a accepting your answer. thanks.